# (De)Serializing "Object"s

Tags: .net, serialization, xml-serialization

I have to XML (de)serialize the following class:

[image]

this gives the following output:

```
<ArrayOfPropertyFilter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PropertyFilter>
    <AndOr>And</AndOr>
    <LeftBracket>None</LeftBracket>
    <Property>17</Property>
    <Operator>Equal</Operator>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">lll</Value>
    <RightBracket>None</RightBracket>
  </PropertyFilter>
</ArrayOfPropertyFilter>
```

and, after deserialization it gives
[image]

How can I "tell" to Serializer to keep the Value "as is", without any XML node....(in the concrete case the Value should be "lll" and not XMLNode containing Text "lll") ?

## EDIT

Bellow is a full working sample in C#. The output is

> Value is = 'System.Xml.XmlNode[]'

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication13
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PropertyFilter filter = new PropertyFilter();
            filter.AndOr = "Jora";
            filter.Value = "haha";
            filter.Property = 15;

            var xml = filter.SerializeToString();
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

            PropertyFilter cloneFilter = xmlDoc.Deserialize<PropertyFilter>();

            Console.WriteLine("Value is = '{0}'", cloneFilter.Value);
        }
    }

    public class PropertyFilter
    {
        public string AndOr { get; set; }
        public string LeftBracket { get; set; }
        public int Property { get; set; }
        public string Operator { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
        public string RightBracket { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Utils
    {
        public static string SerializeToString(this object instance)
        {
            if (instance == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(
                instance.GetType(), null, new Type[0], null, null);
            serializer.Serialize(sw, instance);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public static T Deserialize<T>(this XmlDocument xmlDoc)
        {
            XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc.DocumentElement);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            object obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            T myT = (T)obj;
            return myT;
        }

    }
}
```

## EDIT 2

To stress the Anton answer, the second example (updated with the Groo's remarks):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication13
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PropertyFilter filter = new PropertyFilter();
            filter.AndOr = "Jora";
            var obj = new Hehe();
            obj.Behehe = 4526;
            filter.Value = obj;
            filter.Property = 15;

            var xml = filter.SerializeToString();
            PropertyFilter cloneFilter = xml.Deserialize<PropertyFilter>();

            Console.WriteLine("Value is = '{0}'", cloneFilter.Value);
        }
    }

    public class Hehe
    {
        public int Behehe { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("behehe is '{0}'", Behehe);
        }
    }

    public class PropertyFilter
    {
        public string AndOr { get; set; }
        public string LeftBracket { get; set; }
        public int Property { get; set; }
        public string Operator { get; set; }
        //[XmlElement(typeof(Hehe))]
        public object Value { get; set; }
        public string RightBracket { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Utils
    {
        public static string SerializeToString(this object instance)
        {
            if (instance == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(instance.GetType(), null, new Type[0], null, null);
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(sw, instance);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public static T Deserialize<T>(this string xmlString)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlString))
            {
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the XML you are expecting ?

Comment: @Seb As I mentioned, I want my deserialized Value be object(string) not an XmlNode. I demonstrated the Xml format just for curiosity, I don't care about Xml, but about the deserialized value...

Comment: If this property is going to contain only strings, then why don't you simply change its type to `string`? But if it can contain **any** `object`, then you obviously need to store the type information somewhere.

Comment: @Groo the post is about deserializing Objects, not strings. the information about type can be obtined via `object.GetType()` method... I gave an example with string, but there could be any object.

Comment: @serhio: update your question with the XML schema you need to have. You will most probably need to resort to custom serialization (by explicitly implementing `IXmlSerializable`) to serialize an object this way.

Comment: @Groo no need any custom serialization. I serialize an object, I want an Object back. But I recieve (after deserialization) instead of an object an XmlNode.

Comment: @serhio: any code which wants to deserialize your xml into a real CLR object needs to know **the exact type** of the object in order to create it. This is why `XmlSerializer` creates an `XmlNode`, which contains this information (in your case, it has a xsi:type attribute with the value `"xsd:string"` - this is your object's type). So, in any case, you need to **save this type information somewhere** in order to be able to retrieve later. As @Seb and myself pointed out, if you want to store this **type** information in some specific way, please describe it in your question.

Comment: @Groo I don't understand what you mean. As I said, the exact type of the boxed in a "object" field can be obtained via thisObject.GetType() method. I don't want to store anywhere this type, because it's easily obtained every time using this function. I just need to deserialize exactly the thing I serialized. I serialized an object, that contains a string, i want back an object that contains the string. Its all I want.

Comment: @serhio: let's say you store an **integer** value boxed in that object field (let's say 10). During deserialization, how should .NET decide whether this value should be interpreted as a string `"10"`, a double `10d`, or an integer `10`? You **can** get a type of an object **after** deserialization, but .NET needs to know it **during** deserialization. And @Seb's answer does just that. I've tried it: after deserialization, `Value` property contains an actual string, not a `XmlNode` (regardless of the XML you are getting), so it might be best if you posted your code.

Comment: @Groo I added a sample..... "how should .NET decide"? Once again `object.GetType`. If no, why the value isn't stored as is, as "object", not a integer or string? And once again `object.GetType`.

Comment: @serhio: I feel like we are not understanding each other. Can you answer this question: imagine that I have just sent you an XML file containing the following text: `<Value>10d</Value>`. You start your application and it deserializes the file into an object. **What will be the type of your Value property after deserialization, and why?**

Comment: @Groo This is philosophical question. I added a sample. I need that the deserialized object be identical to the initial. If you can help, please do it. PS. I have `<LeftBracket>None</LeftBracket>` - this goes to an enumeration without problems.

Comment: @serhio : My guess is that the `XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader)` overload doesn't behave like `XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader)`. Try to change the way you provide the XML to the deserializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gree's solution will work as long as `Value` takes values of primitive, XSD-defined types like `string` and `int`, or user-defined types mentioned somewhere in `T`'s definition (`T` itself, the types of its properties etc.) As soon as you need to deserialize a value of a type different from these, you must declare *all* possible types of `Value` with `XmlElementAttribute`, e.g.

```
[XmlElement (typeof (string))]
[XmlElement (typeof (int))]
[XmlElement (typeof (MyType), Namespace = "http://example.com/schemas/my")]
public object Value { get ; set ; }
```

Comment: so, you are trying to explain, that the "object" type is not deserializable in a "object" type, but in a "sample" type listed somewhere....

Comment: Yes. The XML serializer must know about all your types in advance to deserialize them. In your case, when it encounters the `<LeftBracket>` node, XML deserializer can convert the string 'None' to a value of your enum type because it knows that the property `LeftBracket` has this enum type. For a property of type `object`, either you must tell the XML deserializer what types to expect or deserialize it manually.

Comment: @serhio, Anton: there is no need for all of this if you use a `TextReader` instead of a `XmlReader`.

Comment: Actually you do need this sometimes, see post.

Comment: @Anton: That's correct, I disregarded that fact. It's just that I dislike having to remember to update this attribute whenever I decide to add a new type. Well, serializing an object without type information is a bit strange in any case (actually, I rarely use plain `object` properties for anything). Also, this way the "Value" property gets "lost" in the resulting XML (ints are serialized as `<int>` elements, strings as `<string>`, etc.) - not that it matters to OP anyway.

Comment: It won't get 'lost' if you specify e.g. `[XmlElement (typeof (string), ElementName="Value")]`. But I agree that it is awkward to use and should not be used without extra good reasons.

Comment: "I rarely use plain `object` properties for anything." I rarely use too. As usual generics help. But this is the case when they can't. And, after all, I can't just enumerate all kind types potentially used by the object value....

Comment: Why not? If e.g. they have a common base class, you can do that easily at runtime before you construct the XML serializer. Then for every such type, create and add the required `[XmlElement]` attribute as an attribute override. This is the only one robust option. Doing manual serialization will require some serious trickery because there is no way to create an object and tell the XML serializer 'now deserialize this XML into this object'. It is probably doable, but I really can't recommend such an approach.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, that makes sense, you were using a `XmlDocument` for deserialization. Simply use a `String` (or any stream reader, like @Seb [already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597933/deserializing-objects/7599493#7599493)), and it will work:

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static string SerializeToString(this object instance)
    {
        if (instance == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(instance.GetType());

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(sw, instance);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(this string xmlString)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// serialize
var xml = filter.SerializeToString();

// deserialize
var cloneFilter = xml.Deserialize<PropertyFilter>();
```

**[Edit]**

Also, as a side note: never forget to dispose objects implementing `IDisposable`. That's why the `using` constructs are added for any instantiated `Stream`.

**[Edit2]**

As Anton said, in this case you need to specify extra types explicitly, because `XmlSerializer` doesn't search for all possible types to find a matching class.

A *slightly* better solution might be to use a `XmlSerializer` overload which accepts these types (so that you don't need to manually add attributes):

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(this string xmlString)
{
    Type[] typesToInclude = GetAllPossibleTypes();

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), typesToInclude);
    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlString))
    {
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
    }
}
```

This can be done once, at application startup, but you do need to provide the appropriate assembly (or several assemblies) to make sure that all possible types are covered:

```
public static class Utils
{
    private static readonly Type[] _typesToInclude = GetPossibleUserTypes();

    private static Type[] GetPossibleUserTypes()
    {
        // this part should be changed to load types from the assembly
        // that contains your potential Value candidates
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(PropertyFilter));

        // get public classes only
        return assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsPublic && !t.IsAbstract).ToArray();
    }

    public static string SerializeToString(this object instance)
    {
        if (instance == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(instance.GetType(), _typesToInclude);

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(sw, instance);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(this string xmlString)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), _typesToInclude);
        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To be fair, this is what @Seb actually wrote in the first place, so I believe the credit goes to him/her.

Comment: Thank for the remarks. But Anton Tykhyy has reason too. See my second sample. Without the attribute the serialization fails.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this but I'm not sure of what you're trying to achieve.

```
public class PropertyFilter
{
    public string AndOr {get; set;}
    public string LeftBracket {get; set;}
    public int Property {get; set;}
    public string Operator {get; set;}
    public object Value {get; set;}
    public string RightBracket {get; set;}
}
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"Input.xml"))
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PropertyFilter[]));
            PropertyFilter[] deserialized = (PropertyFilter[])serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```

I just put your sample XML in `Input.xml` file. I hope this will help.

Comment: sorry, didn't pay attention to the properties... The Value field is not string, but Object. The question is about deserializing Objects, not strings... With strings as all OK. I gave an example with string, but there could be any object.

Comment: @serhio : I changed the type of the propert but the mechanism is the same.

Comment: I understand the mecanism, but I don't like the result. Instead of Object in the deserialied object I have an XmlNode as you can see in the image. I serialize as Value an Object, but deserialize... an XmlNode! Is not good.

Comment: just to be clear, I used the "mechanism" you describe BEFORE posting that question, in order to obtain the deserialized value. So does not worth posting that as answer, because the question was how to obtain proper value, and not how to (de)serialize. Merci en tout cas d'avoir essayé de m'aider.